# Ember 1.3+ possible memory leak

Tags: javascript, ember.js, memory-leaks

We have spent the past 4 months building an application in EmberJS.  Due to our client's requirements, we chose not to use Ember Data as they didn't want dependencies that were in an alpha state, so we put together our own data layer that is relatively simple.  We define service classes that define routes and dataAdapters that can call multiple services and present the data in a usable format.  What we have started to notice is that the memory consumption keeps going up until the application becomes so overloaded that it fails to respond in a reasonable amount of time.

I have run the Chrome timeline recorder and when we are loading data, we are seeing some XHR loads result in large net memory increases, 1 to 10 MB jumps, when the data is 10K or less.  I also ran the recorder against another website built with an identical service/dataAdapter architecture (minus the ember deferreds/promises) and I didn't see any such spikes and the memory showed expected levels.

Here is our code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var dataAdapter = new App.StatusDataAdapter();

    return dataAdapter.load()
        .then(function(results) {
            return results.statuses;
        });
  }
});

(function($) {
    $.mockjax({
        url: '/config/status_lists/task_status',
        type: 'GET',
        responseText: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']
    });
})(jQuery);

App.StatusService = (function () {  
    function init() {
        return {
            load: function() {
                "use strict";

                var url = '/config/status_lists/task_status',
                    self = this,
                    hash = {
                            url: url,
                            type: 'GET',
                            context: this,
                            dataType: 'json'
                        };

                return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    hash.success = function(json) {
                        Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
                    };

                    hash.error = function(jqXHR) {
                        Ember.run(null, reject, adapter.ajaxError(jqXHR));
                    };

                    return Ember.$.ajax(hash);
                });
            }
        };
    }

    return init;
})();

App.StatusDataAdapter = (function () {  
    function init() {
        return {
            load: function() {
                "use strict";

                var service = new App.StatusService(),

                promises = {
                    statuses: service.load(),
                    status2: service.load(),
                    status3: service.load(),
                    status4: service.load(),
                    status5: service.load()
                };

                return Ember.RSVP.hash(promises)
                    .then(function (results){
                        console.log('statuses loaded');
                        return results;
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    return init;
})();
```

I have put together a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jessesanders/95fP5/ that closely mimics what we are doing.  Each time I click run, I see the memory jump up until it hits about 100 MB, and then it stops increasing.  This concerns me because this is a super simple example with a small data payload.  We are doing a lot more loads with much bigger data payloads and watching the browser come to a halt.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Do we need to explicitly release resources or are doing something wrong that is causing this?  I don't have the choice to use Ember Data, so I have to make this data work and work well.  All help and ideas are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a little tough to actually pinpoint a memory issue in Ember from a jsfiddle.  Just putting Hello World into jsfiddle and clicking run multiple times the memory increases.  I just got it up to 130 MB, http://jsfiddle.net/vbZTX/.

Comment: I would probably guess an event leak over a memory leak.  Are you hooking up any manual jquery events in your page?  Granted you did say the memory was increasing, so maybe it is.  Have you ran a profiler and gotten an idea of what objects are being retained?

Comment: @kingpin2k - I originally wrote this code outside of fiddle and the memory increases on every run (worrysome though about your hello world example in fiddle).  There are no other events wired up for this example so I don't see how events could be effecting it.  In my real world example, GC isn't happening and these large spikes in memory usage are retained, which then lead to the app crashing or the browser coming to a crawl.  I suspect that the memory leak is happening in the ember rsvp promise, however I don't know... Also, not sure how to run the profiler and interpret the results.